# How to run multiple perl instances of same script?

Tags: linux, windows, perl, scripting

So I'm trying to run 1 perl script multiple times but I am only able to run the first time while getting a permission denied message for the all other instances.

```
ERROR: (HTTP::Daemon: Permission denied) at script.pl line 50.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What deos the script do? Does it open a port?

Comment: Can you share a simplified version of your script.pl so we see what you are trying to do? But at first glance it seems you are trying to run multiple HTTP daemons. Do they have different local ports?

Comment: We can't tell you without a bit more detail on what your script is doing.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, your script creates a web server that listens on a specific port. Only one socket can be bound to a port at a time, so the attempt to create the second one fails.

The solution is probably to avoid binding to a specific port.

1. Remove `LocalPort => ...` from the arguments passed to `HTTP::Daemon->new`.
2. After the HTTP::Daemon object is created, get the port using `$d->peerport()`.
3. Communicate the port to the client that will connect to the HTTP server.
4. Have the client connect to the communicated port instead of the one to which it currently connects.